# Can't subtract two doubles mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make some math operation on two fields "price" and "numberOfHours". Both of them are Double type. But it displays me information that it's impossible because "only supports numeric types, not string". Start and end is Date type.
This is aggregation:

```
db.bookings.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            price: 1,
            numberOfHours: {
                        $multiply: [
                            {
                                $divide: [
                                    {
                                        $subtract: ["$end", "$start"]
                                    },
                                    3600000
                                ]
                            },
                            35
                        ]

                    }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            netWorth: {
                $multiply: [
                "$price",
                "$numberOfHours"
            ]
            }

        }
    }
])
```

It display me info: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string. When i change math operation to "$subtract" - "cant $subtract adouble from a string".
So i checked types of this fields and discovered that both of them are Double type:
[This is type of fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVyyJ.png)

Comment: On a side note: I had "null" entries in my arrays which mongo could not evaluate so I had to make sure (from my JavaScript code) to write actual null, e.g. myArray.push(null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following input document:

```
{ _id: 1, price: 2,  end: ISODate(), start: ISODate("2019-12-08T00:00:00.000Z") }
```

and the aggregation query below (your own code, re-formatted):

```
db.test.aggregate( [
{
  $project: {
      price: 1,
      numberOfHours: {
         $multiply: [
             { $divide: [ 
                    { $subtract: [ "$end", "$start" ] }, 
                     3600000 ] 
             },
             35
         ]
       }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
      netWorth: {
          $multiply: [
              "$price",
              "$numberOfHours"
          ]
      }
  }
}
] )
```

The first `$project` stage returns: `{ "_id" : 1, "price" : 2, "numberOfHours" : 900.52865 }`

The second `$project` stage returns: `{ "_id" : 1, "netWorth" : 1801.0573 }`.

There are *no errors* in running the query (even if I switch the operators from multiply to subtract).

The link you had provided "This is type of fields" doesn't have the `end` field. It is possible that the input documents in the `bookings` collection you are using may be having wrong field types for *some documents*. You may want to try the query with one or two sample documents (like I had posted above) and check the results again.

Comment: When i am trying to subtract two double i am getting error: "cant $subtract adouble from a string"

Comment: You can perform subtraction with two doubles. _It is possible that one of the input document has a string in place of a double_. Please browse thru the documents and see if you can find it.